# How to deploy an Azure Function (along with it's code) using Azure Resource Manager template?

Tags: azure, templates, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

We want to create a resource manager template to deploy an azure function. The template json file as well as the code for the function itself will be hosted in a public location (most likely github). So far, we have created the template to accept user input (such as an email address), created the function code, but we are not able to find out how to specify the code location in the template json. (AWS allowed us to host the lambda code as a zip file in an S3 bucket, which will be picked up by their cloud formation template. Just host the template json and the code zip file in an S3 bucket and you are done. it was very simple!)

We have pored over multiple documents and tutorials, but still not able to figure out where to host the code, and how to specify it's location in the template json. We are seeing examples where we find that the code is specified inline in the json template, which we don't want to do. We would rather supply the code in a separate zip file.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your scenario, maybe the [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-function-app-dedicated-github-deploy) is you need.

In your template, using following example to add source code.

```
"resources": [{

            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",

            "name": "web",

            "type": "sourcecontrols",

            "dependsOn": [

                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"

            ],

            "properties": {

                "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",

                "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",

                "IsManualIntegration": true

            }

        }]
```

Comment: how to specify the zip file available in the build artifacts generated via vsts?

Answer (score 0):

To run from a blob container in a storage account, consider using `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` though you will have to create that and get the zip into the location referenced.  This would go in your the `appSettings` array of your functionApp in the ARM.

Alternatively there is `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP` [1] but may be superseded by `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`.

With either option, watch out that you will need to synchronize the triggers with something like:

```
az resource invoke-action --resource-group ${resource_group_name} --action syncfunctiontriggers --name ${function_app_name} --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites"
```

[0] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package
[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push